# Issues with background image on website

Tags: html, css

I need a website and I have coded a landingpage until I finish the full page.

However, I have run into an issue on mobile devices.

The page looks beautiful on my PC as well as on vertical view on my phone, but as soon as I tilt my phone to horizontal mode, the background freaks out and starts showing wrong.

I have read through my code quite a few times and I cannot for the life of me figure out what is messing up the backgroundimage.

I therefore seek your guidance.

Source code is:

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Echers Media</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300i,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
            <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div id="content"><img class="logo" src="../billeder/echersmedialogo.png">
                                <h4>Lyd, video, grafik, webdesign & programmering</h4>
                                <h3><em>- Branding personliggjort ét sted</em></h3>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="info">
                                        <h4>Vi arbejder på at lancerer vores nye hjemmesiden hurtigst muligt.</h4>
                                    <p>Mail: <strong>kontakt@echersmedia.dk</strong><br>
                                    Tlf.: <strong>28 26 95 94</strong><br>
                                    Cvr.: <strong>37899860</strong></h4>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    body {
    background: url(../billeder/baggrund.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #353535;
}

.info {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

#content {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10%;
    size: 50%
}

.logo {
    width: 40%;
}


hr {
    border-top: 1px solid #353535;;
    border-bottom: 1 solid #353535;
    width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: Hm, everything looks fine to me https://imgur.com/a/iG0d2Gw

Comment: @VladimirJovanović after changing the logo size to 20% it seems to look ok, however, the image is very small when holding the phone in vertical position.

It didn't look as it was supposed to earlier though...
Not on my phone (in horizontal position), nor on my laptop.

But again, after changing the logo to 20% size, it seems to have 'fixed' the issue, now the logo is just really small on the vertical position on phone :)

Comment: Look for `@media query in CSS` on Google, that will fix your issue if you are having trouble with layout.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your I don't see much which could break your background image in the  body. One suggestion I can give you is you can add `background-repeat: no-repeat` so that background image doesn't get repeated.

Comment: I will give that a try.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work as intended. It did indeed "lock" the image, but it didn't scale up or down to fill the page. It would simply stop when exceeding the image size. And I actually find that rather weird as I'm watching on my laptop as well, which is causing the same error and the image is a 4K image, so it should be able to fill the entire page on almost all screens.

Comment: Ok, so I changed the logo size all the way down to 20% and it definately did something, but now it's just extremely small on the phone...
Could something like "max-width" fix something?

Comment: @EchersMedia after looking at the background image you can make below update on body which will solve the problem of background image:
`body {
    background: url(../billeder/baggrund.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #353535;
}`

Comment: Hi again.

Unfortunately the background still shows up wrong in the horizontal mode on my phone as seen here:

http://imgur.com/FLcLHg0